# Image variant with only width to retain proportions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

When you want a certain size of an image, `variant` can be used:

```
image_tag user.avatar.variant(resize: "100x#100!")
```

Is it possible to only give the `width` in order to retain the image proportion?
So that the height will be proportionally to the width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. Based on documentation: [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html)

I assume you already have `gem "image_processing"` in you gem file. This gem uses two libs to process images:

- MiniMagic (default). [docs](https://github.com/janko/image_processing/blob/master/doc/minimagick.md#resize_to_fit)
- Vips. [docs](https://github.com/janko/image_processing/blob/master/doc/vips.md#resize_to_limit)

From the docs you can see that it possible to pass nil for height/width.